# Spring long polling request async with DeferredResult

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous, long-polling

I'm facing a problem with Spring using DeferredResult to get an async behaviour.

Spring has a Chat Sample: http://spring.io/blog/2012/05/16/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-chat-sample/

I was wondering how to implement similar behavior, from differents Controller.

Controller1 has a method called findModified(), which returns DeferredResult> that were modified from Controller2

Controller2 has a method called update(), which will setResult() to defferedResult from Controller1

I really cant figure out how to access list of requests in Controller1 from Controller2, because Spring manages controller instances under the hood.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!!

Comment: This isn't a good design, since it strongly couples the two requests (have to go to the same server, etc.). Instead, generate some key and return it to the client, and put the result in some repository under that key when available. An in-memory map or Redis would work.

Comment: Why is that a bad design?
I have 2 differents controllers (have more than 2 indeed) that should release the DeferredResult, I was think about static list of requests...

Comment: What happens when you restart the server or have more than one behind a load balancer? And static anything is always a big red flag.

Comment: I see, can you give me more detail to "Key" workaround that you explained above?